# Unable to change the OG membership type

Tags: 7, organic-groups

I'm trying to add a "restricted" group membership type to only show teasers of a content type to some members. I'm calling the following function from a Rules action; however, the membership ends up being a OG_MEMBERSHIP_TYPE_DEFAULT.

```
function mymodule_subscribe_restricted($account, $group) {
  og_group($group->gid, array('entity type' => 'user', 
    'entity' =>  $account,     
    'state' => OG_STATE_ACTIVE, 
    'membership type' => MYMODULE_OG_RESTRICTED)); 
}
```

Looking at the source code of og_group(), the membership type should go through. And it's defined correctly in the db table og_membership_type.

Any quick pointers or should I just refactor the whole thing to use a separate group role instead of a membership type?

Answer (score 1):

Found out this is an existing issue with OG 7.x-1.4: http://drupal.org/node/1572480.